# Securing and permitting access to spring rest controller with ant matcher and method level security side-by-side?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

First of all my application is build with spring boot and security.

So I have several rest controllers (resources). One controller provides multiple methods to get/post different kind of data. But I have cases where some methods should be public and others needs authentication.

For example:

- GET /api/object/method1  <-- Needs authentication
- GET /api/object/method2  <-- Public
- POST /api/object/method3 <-- Needs authentication
- POST /api/object/method4 <-- Public

What is best practice to secure this resource? I can't secure url with antMatcher with following pattern /api/object/**. Because then the public methods would be secured as well. Also I can't secure by request type (GET, POST).

One option I thought about was using only method level security (eg @Secured etc). This would mean that I need to annotate a lot of methods.

Another thought that comes to mind is dividing resource to 2 parts.
For example creating

- ObjectResource.java
- ObjectResourcePublic.java

One controller base URL would be /api/public/ and second simply /api/
Then I could use antMatcher for these URLS.

Is my only option to secure every path separtely or every method separetly?
What other options do I have to do this kind of partial securing one resource?

Answer (score 0):

You may use below methods apart from above mentioned methods.
1. Write Interceptor/filter
2. Use Aspect and define advise